# Ruby Rails: Control flow in the basic blog application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a total newbie to ruby rails, and i went through the basic tutorial and a sample blogging application with postgresql backend, in the [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Although i kind of got the gist of it, i really didnt understand how the application accesses the postgresql at the backend and also didnt understand the application flow and few keywords which occur in the controller and view files, for example the below line which appears in the index.html.erb file.

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
```

For instance, i didnt understand the edit_post_path(post) keyword. Can someone please point me to a good source for understanding the very basics of rails?

Comment: This guide specifically answers your question - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to the Rails developer community!

Resources:

- [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)
- [Getting Started RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/310-getting-started-with-rails)

---

**MVC**

The core principle of Rails is it's a full-stack [MVC framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

```
MVC = Model - View - Controller
```

If you can learn how this works, it will be the foundation knowledge you need to make good progress. Rails does not work like "standard" websites -- it's a full blown application development framework which works with the MVC principle:

[image]

---

**Data**

The "flow" of data through an MVC application centers on the user

The user requests a page (by typing / clicking on a [Rails route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)), the request is sent to a controller, which may pull data from the model. The data is kept in an external database (can be MYSQL / PGSQL / anything), and works by connecting through a `gem`

Your job as a developer is to make sure the user is presented with the correct data & options at the right time

---

**Question**

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
```

This is a link to the `edit` `post` path, which will be defined in your `config/routes.rb` file. This path will load up this file / method:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def edit
    #your code
end
```

This will then render a particular view file for your users to use. There's a lot more to explain other than this, but I hope this gives you the help you need

Comment: Thank you all for the kind responses. :)

Comment: just got stuck at one point here.. In the posts_controller.rb file, i changed the edit function name to editn, and still the application worked fine. And i am totally lost. Can someone please explain whats happening here.. I have to admit i am a dummy when it comes to RoR, and its a tough cookie..

Comment: I dont see any error when i either mention edit or edit123 or anything, in the controller.. first thing, in the controller i see that the edit function is empty, so i presume its of no significance and that means that the view might be directly hitting the backend db to store or to fetch the values, am i right?.. please correct me if i am wrong.. :)

Comment: If the `edit` action is empty, it won't do anything to process your request! You should put something in there, like this: `def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end`